# RelatedTo field of Email message

Tags: email, sobject, emailmessage, activityhistory

RelatedTo field has multiple lookups to various object for my instance its heavily populated as follows:

> Lookup(Contract,Campaign,Organization,Donation,Product,Asset,Case,Solution,Asset Relationship,List Email,Volunteers Current Job Status,Account Soft Credit,NPSP Package Settings,Manual Recurring Donations,Contacts And Orgs Settings,Relationship,Household,Households Settings,User Rollup Field Settings,Affiliation,Affiliations Settings,Apsona item,Payment,Payment Field Mapping Settings,Custom Field Mapping,Custom Installment Settings,DEPRECATED-RD Error Queue,Recurring Donations Settings,Job Recurrence Schedule,Volunteer Hours,Volunteer Job,Volunteer Recurrence Schedule,Volunteer Shift,Volunteers Settings,abc,Batch,CA Donations,Donation Amount,Donation Setting,Fundraise Amount,Fundraise Setting,IPN,CauseICan Log,Cause I Can Payment,Cause I Can Recurring Payment,Team Member,Document Action,GoogleAppsSettings,Google Apps Domain,Google Apps Settings,Google Tokens,Automatic Subscription,Email Tracking History,Campaign Monitor Campaign,Campaign Monitor Client,Custom Field Mapping,Progress,Queue Item,Smart Email Recipient,Smart Email,Smart Email Variable,Smart Email Mapping,Subscriber List,Subscriber List Member,sendit campaign,sendit campaign status,sendit clients,sendit error,sendit lists,sendit settings,sendit sub rule,sendit user client,Document Request,RS Document Settings,Import Definition,Import Settings,Import,DEPRECATED-Opportunity Rollup Errors,Relationship Auto-Create,DEPRECATED-Relationship Error,Relationship Lookup,Relationship Settings,Address Verification Settings,Address Verification Settings-DEPRECATED,Address,GAU Allocation,Allocations Settings,Batch Data Entry Settings,Batch,NPSP Data Import,Data Import Settings,Engagement Plan Task,Engagement Plan Template,Engagement Plan,Error Settings,Error,DEPRECATED-Fund,General Accounting Unit,Deliverable,Household Naming Settings,Level,Opportunity Naming Settings,Partial Soft Credit,DEPRECATED-Schedulable,Trigger Handler,Fields to Exclude from Sync,Duplicate Check Duplicate,Duplicate Check Log,Duplicate Check Audit,DC Cross Object,Duplicate Check Delta,DC Discard,Duplicate Check Frequent Word,Duplicate Check Group,Duplicate Check Index,Duplicate Check Job,Duplicate Check Layout,DC License,DC Merge,DC Object,DC Record Type Match,DC Record Type Scenario,DC Result Field,DC Scenario Field,DC Scenario,DC Settings,Duplicate Check Temp File,Subscriber Import,AccountContact,Agent Settings,CldExtCfg,CldIn,Log,POSync,PO,SearchFilter,NPSP Data Import Batch,Duplicate Check Queue,Fundraise Item Purchase,Fundraise Item,Deprecated (Do not use),TaskRay Task,TaskRay Project,TaskRay View Project,TaskRay Baseline,TaskRay Task Group Baseline,TaskRay Task Baseline,TaskRay Board Filter Detail,TaskRay Filter Share,TaskRay Filter User Settings,TaskRay Board Filter,TaskRay Board Power Filter,TaskRay Checklist,TaskRay Checklist Item,TaskRay Team,TaskRay Dependency,TaskRay Global Settings,TaskRay History,TaskRay Metadata Cache,TaskRay Pending Action,TaskRay Project Notification,TaskRay Record Type Mapping,TaskRay Settings,TaskRay Task Group,TaskRay Task Notification,TaskRay Time,Customizable Rollup Settings,Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries,Lookup Child Big,Lookup Child,Lookup Parent,Lookup Rollup Calculate Job,Lookup Rollup Summary Log,Lookup Rollup Summary Schedule Item,Lookup Rollup Summary,sendit segment)

But very few options are available while I try to populate it. The FLS for it is read only but I am still able to edit it or populate it. I have checked the Profile Object permissions and its read only but then why am I able to edit it.

Wondering why all options are not seen in it and why is the field read/write when its read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Allow activities is not enabled for those objects. I need to enable it inorder to get in related to field.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why can't I see all objects?"

Your Related To options may be limited because you don't have Read permission on an object, either because of your profile, or you're missing a license from one or more installed packages. Check your User Detail page to see if you can add some packages to your user account, and make sure you're using the standard System Administrator profile (custom profiles can be missing some objects).

> "Why can I edit a read-only field?"

Most likely, you're a System Administrator. Administrators have the Edit Read-Only Fields permission, which ignores the Read-Only Field Level Security on any field that the user could otherwise edit. If you were to log in as a normal user, the field would indeed be read-only when the field is set to Read-Only. You can check your profile permissions to confirm this permission.

Comment: I can add packages to my account and even the object permissions are read/write. Still can't see all objects in related to field.